# If two users are inside the same instruction at the same time, can I identify them?

Tags: sql, excel, vba, datetime, hive

I have access to this data as an export in excel and also in a table in hive/sql, so I would like either an excel function, vba, or sql query to run that would mark which users were using an order during the same time interval. -- If both Adam & Eve were using instruction 111 during the same time interval, I want to keep both of those records, or make a note beside them on both records.

The data that I'm using has millions of records, and each instruction has up to 100 users inside it at various times & I want to see when any users are inside the instruction during the same timespan.

| Instruction | Username | From Time | To Time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | Adam | 06-10-2023 00:00:00 | 06-10-2023 04:00:00 |
| 111 | Adam | 06-10-2023 04:00:00 | 06-10-2023 05:00:00 |
| 111 | Eve | 06-10-2023 02:00:00 | 06-10-2023 06:00:00 |
| 222 | Adam | 06-10-2023 00:00:00 | 06-10-2023 02:00:00 |
| 222 | Adam | 06-10-2023 02:00:00 | 06-10-2023 05:00:00 |
| 222 | Eve | 06-10-2023 03:00:00 | 06-10-2023 04:00:00 |

I have tried a few things I have been reading about such as self-joining the table, but I'm not doing it right.

```
`SELECT tlc.instruction, tlc.userfullname, tlc.logged_start_date, tlc2.logged_start_date, tlc.logged_end_date, tlc2.logged_end_date
    FROM table1 as tlc, table1 as tlc2

    WHERE tlc.instruction = tlc2.instruction
    AND tlc.userfullname <> tlc2.userfullname
    AND tlc.logged_start_date <= tlc2.logged_start_date
    AND tlc.logged_end_date <= tlc2.logged_start_date`
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What about your attempt is not working as you expected? Or were you hoping someone here would just develop the entire solution for you?

Comment: Has you data a PK?

Comment: So you want a logger?

Comment: How do you actually want to display the result? Suppose Adam had an overlap with Eve and Eve had an overlap with Jo (in the same instruction), how are you going to show that Eve has 2 overlaps and who those overlaps are with?

Comment: @braX I edited the original to show some of the sql.

Comment: @NickW I don't have a good solution for that yet, I think if I can show that they are overlapping at all, I can start working with the data.

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII no, I want to look at who was logged into the same instruction at the same time in history, not proceeding forward.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want basic overlapping data then your SQL is pretty close. In order to avoid duplicates (A overlaps with B and B overlaps with A) then I would change this line:

```
AND tlc.userfullname <> tlc2.userfullname
```

to this:

```
AND tlc.userfullname < tlc2.userfullname
```

In order to get all the possible overlaps the date comparison should probably:

```
AND NOT (tlc.logged_end_date <= tlc2.logged_start_date 
         OR 
         tlc.logged_start_date >= tlc2.logged_end_date)
```

N.B. it is simpler to work out what isn't an overlap and then negate it than code for all the scenarios where there is an overlap

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. please excuse my ignorance, what does the "tlc.userfullname < tlc2.userfullname" i'm confused by the expression. How could a name string be less than another string and how does that change the expression?

Comment: @BenF. Let's say you have an Excel spreadsheet with a column of names. You are able to sort said column of strings. The fact that you can sort a list of strings requires strings to be comparable/have a greater than/less than relationship. Usually this is done with the `Lexicographic order`. The reason for the Use of `<` in this example is the following: Since we have a self join, every combination would be returned twice (once A-B and then B-A). Both A and B have a name where one is greater than the other. So by narrowing the results to those where `nameA > nameB` you eliminate all duplicates

Comment: Strings can be compared in SQL and it is done character by character and uses the characters’ ascii values for comparison purposes. Therefore a string that starts with A is less than a string that starts with B. Therefore, the expression ensures each pair of usernames is only compared once and it compares the lower value in tlc to the higher value in tlc2

Comment: @Lord-JulianXLII interesting, thank you. Would there be a case where Name ZZZZ would always be greater than name AAAA and not return a result even if it fell within my other parameters?

Answer (score 1):

For something to be considered an overlap either the `startDate` or `endDate` of A have to be between the `startDate` and `endDate` of B

So you could query for exactly that.

```
AND (tlc.logged_start_date BETWEEN tlc2.logged_start_date AND tlc2.logged_end_date
     OR
     tlc.logged_end_date BETWEEN tlc2.logged_start_date AND tlc2.logged_end_date)
```

`BETWEEN` is inclusive so equal to `<= x <=`

Comment: Not sure that caters for B being entirely within A

Comment: since A and B tables are 1 table joined on itself, if we cover A is in B, it should also cover B inside A since they're the same table, right?

Comment: @NickW don't we have a self join? - So every element of table1 is also element of table2 - meaning for every combination of records where B is entirely in A there exits the combination of the same two records where A fits entirely into B.